# How to get a row from a usergridview in C#?

Tags: c#, oledb

When I want to add content from a usergridview to an access database with OleDB in C# I have the following code:

```
da.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [some] ([some1], [some2]) VALUES (?,?)");

da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@some1", OleDbType.VarChar, 60, "some1");
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@some2", OleDbType.VarChar, 60, "some2");
```

As far as I have understood the `some1` and `some2` at the end of our `InsertCommands` are the columns in my `usergridview`. Now what I would like to achieve is to edit the content before inserting it into the database. So my actual question is how can I get the "`some1`" outside the `InsertCommand` to put it into a function (**e.g.** `my_function(some1)` should be the Parameter content).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo syntax

```
    public void my_function(string varSome1, string varSome2)
    {
        .
        .
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [some] ([some1], [some2]) Values (@some1, @some2)", yourOleDbConnection);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@some1", varSome1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@some2", varSome2);
        .
        .
        .
        da.InsertCommand = cmd;           
        .
        .
    }
```

**EDIT**

from your other function edit values

```
string editedSome1 = "your edited value1";
string editedSome2 = "your edited value2";
```

then you call

```
my_function(editedSome1, editedSome2);
```

Comment: I dont want the insert command to be inside a function, I would like to have a function to edit my some1 and some2. But I dont know how to get some1 and some2 outside the `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue();`

Comment: Isn't this function doing what you want? Because can edit varSome1, varSome2 before passing onto my_function(). coz varSome1, varSome2 are variables and independent of the insert command. so whatever values you pass will be in place of the variables varSome1, varSome2

Comment: yeah but I want to get the values from my usergridview! In this case `da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@some1", OleDbType.VarChar, 60, "some1");` the "some1" at the end is the content of a row in my usergridview. The problem is that I can use this "some1" only within the `da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add()`. My question is how can I use it outside this Parameters.Add function?

Comment: I figured out that this code will give me the first row and third cell of my datagridview: `string str = userDataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();`. The problem now is that when I add my parameters I dont quite know which row is being processed, somehow the `da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add()` is going through all of the records in my datagridview and adding them...

Comment: Are you trying to insert a new row or are you trying to edit an existing row? Under which event are you trying to do this? can you edit your question with the relevant code (specifically with the event function)